# Стандаpтная обpаботка сообщений DefWindowProc

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Мастер win32 проекта VC++ 2010 создаёт следующий код:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
switch (message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
    {
        EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    }
    break;
}
return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
```

}

Почему здесь не используется стандаpтная обpаботка сообщений DefWindowProc!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему здесь не используется стандаpтная обpаботка сообщений DefWindowProc!?

`DefWindowProc` - это базовый обработчик окна (любого), т.е. это т.с. прародитель всех окон. А диалоговое окно - это надстройка над стандартным окном (потомок прародителя), т.е. у диалога есть собственный класс окна, и, соответственно - собственная **процедура окна**: `DefDlgProc`.

Она может использоваться программистом в том же ракурсе, что и `DefWindowProc`, но при условии, что **в ресурсе диалога**, в свойстве `Class` будет указано имя Вашего собственного класса, который будет унаследован от класса диалога `#32770`.

Вот в **процедуре окна** этого класса и можно использовать `DefDlgProc` вместо `DefWindowProc`.

А **процедура диалога**, указанная Вами вызывается из самой `DefDlgProc` и имеет немного схожую сигнатуру с **процедурой окна**, но совсем иной смысл.

Поэтому очень важно их не путать!

Comment: То есть я не должен использовать DefWindowProc в процедуре диалогового окна? Тогда как же быть возвращаясь к теме: 
http://hashcode.ru/questions/161856/v%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-static-text-c-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-winapi

Comment: Да, здесь придется взвесить, что для Вас важнее:  
1. если первый вариант, то придется писать свой собственный класс, как я описал в текущем ответе.  
2. если Вас устроит второй вариант, то достаточно будет процедуры диалога, т.е. свой класс здесь не потребуется.

Answer (score 1):

Это функция обработки сообщений диалогового окна. См. [здесь](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/dialog/r.php?48) например:

> Возвращаемые значения
>
> Только в ответ на сообщение WM_INITDIALOG, процедура диалогового окна должна возвратить не нулевое значение, если она обрабатывает сообщение, и нуль, если она этого не делает. В ответ на сообщение WM_INITDIALOG, процедура диалогового окна должна возвратить нуль, если она вызывает функцию SetFocus, чтобы установить фокус в один из органов управления в блоке диалога. Иначе, она должна возвратить значение отличное от нуля, в каждом случае, когда система устанавливает фокус в первом элементе управления диалогового окна, которому можно передать фокус.

Answer (score 0):

> Почему здесь не используется стандаpтная обpаботка сообщений DefWindowProc!?

У диалоговых окон оно должно возвращать только true или false. Это в справке описано подробно.